# Scoped lock with if condition

Tags: c++, boost

I want to create scoped lock, but I want something like:

```
{
    if(lockRequired)
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock(Mutex); //After this line we go out of scope
    /* Here I also want to have Mutex */
}
```

if condition is true I want to have lock mutex but in level up scope. I know that I can use simple .lock and in the end of scope use .unlock but I have many return path. I can also create some SynchronizationGuard in scope and whed destructor is called unlock mutex but it's not clean solution. Some advices ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ternary operator.

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock = lockRequired ? 
boost::mutex::scoped_lock(Mutex) : boost::mutex::scoped_lock();
```

Or just use `swap` under condition.

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock;
if (lockRequired)
{
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock_(Mutex);
   lock.swap(lock_);
}
```

Or just construct lock with `defer_lock_t` and then call `lock` function.

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(Mutex, boost::defer_lock);
if (lockRequired)
{
   lock.lock();
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't see you had `defer_lock` in the second part of the answer. The first part strikes me as too hacky to recommend

Answer (score 3):

You can [construct the lock *deferred*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag):

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {

    boost::mutex mx;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock sl(mx, boost::defer_lock);

    if (condition)
        sl.lock();

    // sl will unlock on end of scope
}
```

Also works for `std::unique_lock`, `std::lock_guard` and corresponding boost types

Analogously there's the `adopt_lock` tag type.